# Converting raster layer to vector using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vectorization

I have a raster layer (processed from landsat thermal band). But this data does not contain attribute table. I want to convert this into a vector layer of polygon features; holding an attribute table of temperature data. So I need to convert this to contain an attribute table. I am using ArcGIS software.

Answer (score 5):

ArcGIS has a [Raster to Polygon](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polygon.htm) tool that will do this for you. It's in the conversion toolbox.

I suspect there's a better way to approach your problem, but it's hard to say without knowing more about your analysis.

Comment: I have edited the question. Or suggest me any guideline or so.

Comment: Your edited question is nearly identical to your original question. The Raster to Polygon tool will convert your raster layer to a vector later with an attribute table.

It is rarely a good idea to convert continuous raster data to a vector layer. The vector layer will likely contain thousands of individual polygons that will not be efficient to process. Can you analyze the data in raster format instead?

Comment: Anyway the Raster to Polygon tool wont work here. When trying to add the raster layer to the tool you mentioned it shows the message "one or more items invalid and will not be added to the control".

Answer (score 3):

The data was in float, so I found after some research it needs to be converted into integer first. Using Raster Calculator I used the following syntax to convert into new raster layer. It created an attribute table and I can convert it into vector data now.
Syntax:

> Int("surface_temp.img")

`